# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'includes') at Text.render (Text.js:421:1)

Tags: charts, bar-chart, recharts

Have issue with Multi bar chart when i am trying to run the below code with latest version
Versions:  "recharts": "^2.2.0","react": "^18.2.0","react-dom":
"^18.2.0", "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'includes')
at Text.render (Text.js:421:1)
at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:17164:1)
at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:17121:1)
at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:18747:1)
at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23691:1)
at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22960:1)
at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22883:1)
at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:22856:1)
at recoverFromConcurrentError (react-dom.development.js:22348:1)
at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:22260:1)
```

Code :

```
    import React from 'react'
import {
  BarChart, XAxis, YAxis, CartesianGrid, Tooltip, ResponsiveContainer, Bar
} from 'recharts'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { CustomTooltip } from './CustomToolTip'

export default function MultiBarsChart ({ bars, barSize = 25, dataKey = 'name', dataURL, params }) {
  let dataLength = 0
  dataLength = data?.length

  return (
    <div>
      {dataLength !== 0
      ? <ResponsiveContainer height={298} width='100%' margin={0}>
        <BarChart
          height={300} data={data}
          margin={{ top: 5, right: 30, left: 20, bottom: 5 }}
        >

          <XAxis dataKey={dataKey} />
          <YAxis
            type='number'
            yAxisId={0}
            axisLine={false}
            stroke={null}
          />
          <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray='1 0' vertical={false} />
          <Tooltip content={<CustomTooltip />} />
          {bars.map((bar) =>
            <Bar barSize={barSize} key={bar.id} dataKey={bar.name} fill={bar.color} />
          )}
        </BarChart>

      </ResponsiveContainer>
    : <div className='overall-title'>There is no data available.</div>}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Library: Rechart

```
data:  [
{"incomplete": 12,"complete": 7,"name": "abc"},       
{'incomplete": 31,"complete": 25,"name": "bdc"} 

bars=[
{ name: 'complete', id: 1, color: '#7500c0' }, 
{ name: 'incomplete', id: 2, color: '#c4cdd5' }
]
```

Comment: Could you also share an example dataset with which you achieve this result?

Comment: I do not understand where `data` comes from in the component. Please also provide a sample configuration, i.e. what is bars set to?

Comment: Hi Thanks For the Reply @Nikolas Rieble. the data comes from the parent component . Data Looks like below"                     
      `data:  [
      {
        "incomplete": 12,
        "complete": 7,
        "name": "abc"
      },
      {
        "incomplete": 31,
        "complete": 25,
        "name": "bdc"
      } `                                                                                                                                   **bars={[{ name: 'complete', id: 1, color: '#7500c0' },
                { name: 'incomplete', id: 2, color: '#c4cdd5' }]}**

Comment: I got the solution to the issue, which is that we should not pass the stroke as null for the y axis.

Comment: Please write an answer for you own question then.